# I want to share this JSON DATA when user click on share button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-shared-element

**This is JSON DATA**

```js
{
  "sad": [
    { "id": "1", "title": "hello this is no.1" },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "आँखें थक गई है आसमान को देखते देखते पर वो तारा नहीं टूटता ,जिसे देखकर तुम्हें मांग लूँ"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "title": "मेरी हर आह को वाह मिली है यहाँ…..,कौन कहता है दर्द बिकता नहीं है !"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "title": "तुझसे अच्छे तो जख्म हैं मेरे । उतनी ही तकलीफ देते हैं जितनी बर्दास्त कर सकूँ"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "title": "रुठुंगा अगर तुजसे तो इस कदर रुठुंगा की ये तेरीे आँखे मेरी एक झलक को तरसेंगी !!"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "title": "बेवफा लोग बढ़ रहे हैं धीरे धीरे, इक शहर अब इनका भी होना चाहिए"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "title": "बेवफा लोग बढ़ रहे हैं धीरे धीरे, इक शहर अब इनका भी होना चाहिए"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "title": "बेवफा लोग बढ़ रहे हैं धीरे धीरे, इक शहर अब इनका भी होना चाहिए"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "title": "बेवफा लोग बढ़ रहे हैं धीरे धीरे, इक शहर अब इनका भी होना चाहिए"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is my code, I want to know what should I do for share this particular data when user press on share button

*Here I imported all library*

```js
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  ListView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Share,
} from "react-native";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons";
import SadJson from "./sad.json";

var d = SadJson.sad;

const sad = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  // This is share method code
  const onShare = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await Share.share({
        message: data.toString(d),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(d);
  });

  // This is return section where I use Flatlist for show Data
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        removeClippedSubviews={false}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View>
            <Text>
              {item.id}
              {item.title}
            </Text>

            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.sharebtn} onPress={onShare}>
                <Text>Share{item.id}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.sharebtn}>
                <Text>Copy</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

// This is Style section
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
  },

  sharebtn: {
    width: 60,
    height: 30,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#2BDB25",
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  btntext: {
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});

export default sad;
```

*Please help me and Please let me know how to share this data on social media or any other App*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to share a specific data element from `data` state. To pass a specific object from your `data` to `Share.share` then I suggest you pass the *entire* `item` object to your `onShare` handler from the map callback in the `FlatList`.

Update `onShare` to be consume the `item` object. Also, since you don't actually use the awaited on return value this function probably doesn't need to be `async` (You can add it back if you really do `await` values to use later).

```
const onShare = item => {
  try {
    const result = await Share.share({
      message: item,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error.message);
  }
};
```

And pass the `item` to the callback

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.sharebtn}
  onPress={() => onShare(item)} // <-- pass item to callback
>
  <Text>Share{item.id}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Another suggestion - Since your data is static there isn't much need to populate your state from the `useEffect` hook, especially since that effect hasn't any dependencies and updates state, unless you've a copy/paste issue, as written this effect looks like it should trigger render looping. You can just populate your state with an initial value.

```
const d = SadJson.sad;
...
const [data, setData] = useState(d); // <-- initialize state with the imported JSON data
```